# Access native system APIs when implementing a language with LLVM

Tags: user-interface, compiler-construction, llvm, native

I'm interested in learning about compilers and their creation, so I've been looking into various tools such as LLVM. It seems like a great framework to work with, but I'm a little confused how you can access native APIs with it.

Specifically, I'm interested in creating a language that has GUI or at least a windowing system built in. LLVM doesn't seem to wrap that functionality, so would I manually need to write assembly that called the APIs provided by each system (e.g. Win32)?

For example, the [Red](http://www.red-lang.org/p/about.html) language claims to have a "Cross-platform native GUI system" built in. I assume they manually wrote the backend for that which used different system calls depending on the current system, or piggy backed on Rebol which did that instead.

Is such a thing possible or viable when using LLVM, which does a lot of the backend abstraction for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LLVM does not have an API geared toward abstraction of the use APIs.  What you CAN do is write a runtime library for your language, and then use LLVM to generate runtime calls as needed.  I have some experimentation and found that I preferred to write a runtime in C++ and then create some C bindings.  The C bindings are necessary because C++ name mangling will make it very difficult to link against your runtime library, whereas with C the name of a symbol in a shared lib will be the same as that of the function.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, I would create a C/C++ library that provides cross platform functionality to e.g. create and work with windows, and then link to that with LLVM so that I could call it through their API? And that library could be included in the resulting compiler exectutable? Thanks for the answer and C bindings advice, I appreciate it :)

Comment: That's exactly what I'm suggesting.  Note that if you are using LLVM's JIT it will simply call dlsym (or platform equivalent) to resolve any symbols, so your interpreter program itself must link to the library.  If you statically compile your program, you must link the executable.

Comment: Awesome, good to have something specific to look into. Thanks :)